# Центровка футера

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Я потихоньку пишу сайт, сейчас небольшая запарка вышла с футером: как его можно заузить по ширине? Хочу футер типа как на [этом сайте](http://www.snob.ru/), ток чтоб верхние углы были закруглены... Сайт на 100% ширины экрана!

Comment: здесь больше подойдут теги html css верстка

Comment: Если что-то нужно сделать "как на этом сайте" - то открываете исходный код и смотрите ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
.footer{
  width:990px;
  margin:0px auto;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А не проще без усложнения таблицей стилей?

```
< div align="center">footer< /div>
```

В теге `div` прописываете требуемую ширину вашего footer-а.

Comment: Не проще, вешать стили непосредственно на элементы самое неправильное что только можно сделать. И чем так усложниться файл со стилями если у элемента прописать width:990px. К тому же align="center" уже давно устарел и не должен использоваться.

Answer (score 0):

Можно с использованием `transform`

```
.footer {
   position: absolute;
   width: 990px;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   border-top-left-radius: 5px;
   border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<div class="footer">footer</div>
```

Comment: Гениально.